# Fully automating Microsoft bot framework deployment using ARM (App settings get removed and functionality is missing)

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-resource-manager, direct-line-botframework

I'm currently working on a challenge where I'd like to fully automate the deployment of a Bot Framework application.

Currently we've set it all up to correctly fill the resource group in Azure with:
1. The Bot
2. The AppService handling requests from the Bot
3. An application that uses the DirectLineChannel to forward the conversation from an Amazon Alexa client

---

All these application need some manual steps to be fully setup though:

1. The Bot

   a. Create Skype Channel

   b. Create a Direct Line Channel and copy the DirectLineSecret to be used later

   c. Setting up OAuth for the bot

   [image: Setup OAuth]
2. The App Service for the Direct Line Channel

   a. Create a new AppSetting named DirectLineSecret and paste the earlier copied value in here

---

Part one can be done once so it doesn't have to be done every time, but the second step always needs to be done as the AppSettings get removed by the ARM template every deployment.

An easy solution would be to just include the values inside the parameter file for ARM but that would make my source code dependent on what environments it will deploy to. A second option would be to create a PowerShell script to fill in the AppSettings after the deployment but that would still need to somehow find out what the DirectLineSecret is and then create an AppSetting for it.

Does anyone have any other suggestions regarding this? (Ideally where my code wouldn't have to be changed whenever I want to deploy to a new environment).

Comment: Do you want to do both operations: creating bot service and enabling some channels via ARM template?

Comment: Ideally I would like to execute all steps through ARM yes.

Answer (score 0):

ARM Templates declare a "state" or end goal for a resource.  So if you declare "no app settings" in the template that's what you'll get. Declarative is a bit of a mindset change.

If you need different settings for different environments then you would use parameters to replace that things that need to change from one env to the next.  Assuming you're automated, that automation pipeline is likely aware of the env it's deploying to and can set the parameters values accordingly.

That help?